# python class, that takes in a couple of variables

Tags: python, variables

i would like to write a class that takes in a couple of variables in the form of (`variableName, value`). However variable names are only known at runtime and also the number of args are known at runtime. In my class, i have an object where i want to set those paramaters. So what i need to loop over all variables and setattribute as below.

```
setattr (self.obj, variableName, value)
self.obj.make()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for (variableName, value) in kwargs.items():
            # setattr(), etc.
```

which you would call with `C(x=3, y=123,…)`.

If you really want to use a [variableName, value,…] list of arguments, you can do:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        arg_iter = iter(args)
        for (variableName, value) in zip(arg_iter, arg_iter):
            # setattr(), etc.
```

which you call with `C('x', 3, 'y', 123,…)`.  The `zip()` trick groups arguments of the list of arguments (`args`) by pairs.  You might want to add a check on the number of arguments passed (`C(3)` is accepted by the above code because `zip()` does not mind using two sequences of different length).